# Twitter Bootstrap: Full Page carousel height on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

after a couple of hours trying with the Twitter Bootstrap carousel in their example (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html)

I want the carousel to display the full page height on mobile. a link to my site (http://nathanielmignotte.ca/Work/CottageSite/), as you can see when you shrink the page to mobile view or 480px, but the slider doesn't go to full page width. I've tried using media queries to define a certain break point, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i added the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel for you. Please try and let me know.

[http://jsfiddle.net/TU6LX/]

Thanks

Comment: it doesn't stretch to fit on mobile.

Comment: You just modify the pixels to %.